# Compare two sets of frequencies

Tags: statistical-significance

I have two sets of frequencies representing the rate of each modality of a nominal variable (e.g. A B C D E) amongst X occurences. For exemple, amongst 10 occurences, if A appears 2 times, B 1 time, C 3 times, D 0 time and E 4 times, I will obtain the following distribution:

e.g., 20% 10% 30% 0% 40%

Let's take two samples:

```
          A   B   C   D   E
```

Sample 1 20% 10% 30% 0%  40%

Sample 2 10% 40% 10% 10% 30%

What I would like to know is :

- Is this two distributions significantly different?
- Which modality(ies) generate(s) the overall difference (e.g., B with a difference of 30% between the two samples generates the overall difference found)?

In two different analyses, I deal with dependent (the two samples come from the same subject) and independent (the two samples come from two different subjects) data.

How I can proceed to test samples differences as described above?

Thanks

Comment: Hello. You can use Chi-Squared distribution test on counts (not shares), because counts matter a lot (3 and 30, for 30%, will give dramatically different p-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a chi-squared test for homogeneity of proportions.
Suppose you have 200 subjects in Gp 1 and 190 in Gp2. If Gp 1 is
equally likely to give any one of the five responses, and Gp 2 is
somewhat more likely to answer D or E than A or B, then you might
have data with counts as in the matrix `MAT` below.

```
set.seed(410)
x1 = sample(1:5, 200, rep=T)
x2 = sample(1:5, 190, rep=T, p=c(.1,.1,.2,.3,.3))
c1 = tabulate(x1); c2 = tabulate(x2)
MAT = rbind(c1, c2);  MAT
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
c1   36   38   38   47   41
c2   15   25   28   65   57
```

Then in R, the appropriate chi-squared test gives the following results.

```
chisq.test(MAT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 18.105, df = 4, p-value = 0.001177
```

Thus the two groups give significantly different responses: P-value < 0.05.
In fact, a chi-squared statistic above the 'critical value' 9.488, would lead to rejecting the null hypothesis at the 5% level.

```
qchisq(.95, 4)
[1] 9.487729
```

The figure below shows the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(4).$ The vertical red line is at the critical value. The heavy blue line shows
the value of the chi-squared statistic. The P-value of the test is the area
under the curve to the right of the the heavy blue line.

[image]

As a precaution, you should check the 'expected' counts to make sure all exceed 3 and
most exceed 5. This is a rough rule to assure that the chi-squared statistic
has (nearly) the chi-squared distribution with $(2-1)(5-1) = 4$ degrees of freedom.
For my fake data, sample sizes are large enough that there is no difficulty. [You can look in a statistics textbook to see how expected counts are found from row and column totals of `MAT`: the expected number of A's in Gp 1 is about 26.15, computed in R as shown just below.]

```
e.11 = 200*(36+15)/(200+190);  e.11
[1] 26.15385

chisq.test(MAT)$exp
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]     [,5]
c1 26.15385 32.30769 33.84615 57.4359 50.25641
c2 24.84615 30.69231 32.15385 54.5641 47.74359
```

To get an idea what the pattern of differences between counts of the two groups might be, you can look at Pearson residuals. Their squares add up to the
chi-squared statistic.

Residuals with the largest absolute values show where expected counts (found using the null hypothesis that the groups are the same)
differ from the observed counts. [The R code just below shows how the residual at upper-left was computed.]

```
r.11 = (36-e.11)/sqrt(e.11);  r.11
[1] 1.925302

chisq.test(MAT)$res
        [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
c1  1.925302  1.001464  0.7139959 -1.377013 -1.305710
c2 -1.975318 -1.027481 -0.7325444  1.412786  1.339631
```

For example, under $H_0,$ Gp 2 is expected to have about 25 A's but only 15 were observed.
Also, Gp 2 is expected to have about 48 E's, but 57 were observed.